Use `winrt.windows.media.control` in Node.js or Rust
In the following python code I get the currently playing media / music from windows.
To display it on a electron app i would prefer to get the data using Node.js (or Rust for Tauri):
import asyncio
from winrt.windows.media.control import \
    GlobalSystemMediaTransportControlsSessionManager as MediaManager

async def get_current_media_info():
    sessions = await MediaManager.request_async()
    current_session = sessions.get_current_session()
    if current_session:
        info = await current_session.try_get_media_properties_async()
        return info
    return None

if __name__ == "__main__":
    info = asyncio.run(get_current_media_info())
    if info:
        print(f"Currently playing: {info.thumbnail} by {info.artist}")
    else:
        print("No media is currently playing")


The windows crate exposes the respective WinRT types. The main challenge will be mapping WinRT's async implementation onto your target framework's infrastructure.

Made it in rust
main.rs
use windows::Media::Control::{GlobalSystemMediaTransportControlsSessionManager as MediaSessionManager, GlobalSystemMediaTransportControlsSession};

type Result<T> = std::result::Result<T, Box<dyn std::error::Error>>;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<()> {
    let session_manager = MediaSessionManager::RequestAsync()?.await?;
    let sessions = session_manager.GetCurrentSession()?;

    let info = sessions.TryGetMediaPropertiesAsync()?.await?;
    let title = info.Title()?;
    println!("{}", title);


    Ok(())
}

cargo.toml
[dependencies]
tokio = { version = "1.37.0", features = ["full"] }
windows = { version = "0.56.0", features = ["Media_Control"]}


